# Pyomo + Gurobi - Q matrix is not positive semi-definite (PSD)

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, gurobi

I am solving an optimization program with pyomo and gurobi.Gurobi throws the following error: `Q matrix is not positive semi-definite (PSD). Set NonConvex parameter to 2 to solve model.` I can solve the problem with

```
opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')
opt.options['NonConvex'] = 2
```

I have another formulation of the optimization program which is linear, so what I would like would be something like

```
if programIsConvex:
    opt.options['NonConvex'] = 1
else:
    opt.options['NonConvex'] = 2
```

In other words, check if the program is convex before trying to solve it with gurobi.

Comment: Pass the information about your formulation in use to the place of your if. At some point you decide about your formulation. Just make it accessible to the if. Everything else is meh as: 1) Checking convexity of arbritrary problems is NP-hard. 2) Checking convexity within some restricted special-cases (e.g. a QP) might be easy (although the check you see is one of those which are easy in theory, but not that nice in regards to numerical-robustness) but as gurobi supports many modes, one must take care of this *context*. 3) Exception-handling based *reflection/correction* sounds even worse.

Comment: "I have another formulation of the optimization program which is linear" A linear model is convex automatically (and does not have a Q matrix, by definition). So the nonconvex flag does not apply.

Comment: @sascha But Gurobi is able to say if option setting NonConvex has to be set to 2 or not, so what I am looking for should be doable directly with gurobi